# Cannot get the new object properties after the creation of a new resource in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-resource

I am trying to create a new Resource of the type Person in AngularJS. Once the resource is created, I would like to get the new resource id (which is returned by the server).

```
it('should get the new Person id after add', inject(function($httpBackend, Person) {
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('http://api.example.com/Persons').respond({ "id" : 32});

        var newPerson = new Person();
        newPerson.$save();
        expect(newPerson.id).toEquals(32);

 }));
```

I am getting "Expected undefined to be 32" in Karma.

I thought that my code snippet what very closed to the one provided by the [$Resource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) at the end of the Credit Card code snippet.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `$httpBackend.flush()` to flush requests.

Try this:

```
it('should get the new Person id after add', inject(function($httpBackend, Person) {
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('http://api.example.com/Persons').respond({ "id" : 32});

        var newPerson = new Person();
        newPerson.$save();

        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(newPerson.id).toEquals(32);
 }));
```

Comment: I get: "timeout: timed out after 500 msec waiting for new data is populated"

Comment: I see, you didn't call `$httpBackend.flush()` to flush requests. Edit my answer.